# How to change the angle of data labels on Access 2007 Pivot Charts

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007 and would like to know how to set the custom angle of a PivotChart Data Label

I couldn’t seem to figure out how to do it. I searched everywhere and I do see that there is an DataLabel.Orientation property but this applies to Excel.

If I can’t change the Custom Angle I at least want to adjust the Orientation so it is vertical. Right now its Horizontal and if the figures are in the thousands the numbers overlap each other.

Anyone know the syntax for changing the angle or orientation of a data label? Below is a picture of the PivotChart. Notice that in the 'Properties' window the option to change the orientation is disabled!

[image: Pivot Chart picture with Data labels set horizontally]

Comment: I am not able to get data labels to even show. Try double click on a label. Does that enable Orientation?

Comment: This is easy to accomplish in a chart object on a form or report.

Comment: I tried using a chart object on Access 2007 but for some reason it wasn't loading the data I needed into the object and instead gave me the generic template I always see when I make one.

Comment: So, i would like to know specifically for Pivot Charts as they are a lot more controllable.

Comment: Not seeing any way to do that with Pivot Chart. Keep in mind Access 2013 removes creating Pivot views. The chart object would not show your data in Form view?

Comment: I'll check it out further. Last time I checked it didn't let me, but I'll give it another try